# how to make create and make use of two headers. which can be accessed based on the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newbi to wordpress. I have created a website in wordpress which has totally 6 pages.
here  5 pages use the same header, but only one page has different header. So i how can how to create new header.

header.php(is used by all 5 pages): In this case is used "get_header();" in page.php to call the header.
home.php(to be used by home page). here is ther any possible way to access these new header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the link 
if link is www.test.com/home.php
then use

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'home.php') {  ?>
      <h1>Header for the Homepage</h1>
    <?php } else {  ?>
      <h1>Header for other pages</h1>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways to do this. The easiest would be to use `is_home()` in header.php to check if the currently loaded page is the homepage. You could change the header.php to something like:

```
<?php if(is_home()) {  ?>
  <h1>Header for the Homepage</h1>
<?php } else {  ?>
  <h1>Header for other pages</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: when i tried the above code its always going to the else condition

Comment: Even in wordpress blog i found the same solution but it's not working, don no y its not.

Comment: Oh, I see what I did wrong there. Why did you make a home.php and not just an actual wordpress page with the title home? You can set that page as your homepage in the settings menu. That way this solution works... Alternatively, use the solution posted by Pradeep Singh

Comment: There's a difference between is_font_page() and is_home() in wordpress. 
is_front_page() returns true both when you have a static page OR your main blog page as the homepage. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page